# How to furfill new columns from multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with 2 columns: 'IMO' and 'LOAD_DATE'.
Many IMOs have multiple load dates.

I would like to create another DataFrame with all the dates as index and new columns for each IMO. Each column being furfilled with '0's for the empty days and '1's for the load days.

Input file:

```
    | VESSEL_IMO |    Date 
  1 |    9821    |   16-12-16
  2 |    9821    |   20-12-16
  3 |    9822    |   16-12-16
  4 |    9822    |   17-12-16
  5 |    9823    |   16-12-16
  6 |    9823    |   18-12-16
  7 |    9999    |   15-12-16
  8 |    9999    |   18-12-16
  9 |    9999    |   21-12-16
```

Here is a sample of my code so far which returns me:

*IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : calendrier})

for namm in xl['AS_VESSEL_IMO'].unique():
    df[namm] = 0    
    al_datt = xl[xl['AS_VESSEL_IMO'] == namm]['AS_LOAD_DATE']
    df.ix[df['Date'].isin(al_datt), df[namm]] = 1
```

Desire output:

```
    Date   | 9821 | 9822 | 9823 |...| 9999 
  15-12-16 |   0  |   0  |   0  |...|   1 
  16-12-16 |   1  |   1  |   1  |...|   0 
  17-12-16 |   0  |   1  |   0  |...|   0 
  18-12-16 |   0  |   0  |   1  |...|   1 
  19-12-16 |   0  |   0  |   0  |...|   0 
  20-12-16 |   1  |   0  |   0  |...|   0 
  21-12-16 |   0  |   0  |   0  |...|   1
```

Comment: Can you add sample data with desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : pd.date_range('16-12-2016', periods=10)})
print (df1)
        Date
0 2016-12-16
1 2016-12-17
2 2016-12-18
3 2016-12-19
4 2016-12-20
5 2016-12-21
6 2016-12-22
7 2016-12-23
8 2016-12-24
9 2016-12-25
```

I think you need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and if duplicates `groupby` with aggregating `max`:

```
df['a'] = 1
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'VESSEL_IMO'])['a'].unstack(fill_value=0)

#if duplicates in rows and get ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
#df = df.groupby(['Date', 'VESSEL_IMO'])['a'].max().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
VESSEL_IMO  9821  9822  9823  9999
Date                              
2016-12-15     0     0     0     1
2016-12-16     1     1     1     0
2016-12-17     0     1     0     0
2016-12-18     0     0     1     1
2016-12-20     1     0     0     0
2016-12-21     0     0     0     1
```

And last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.reindex(df1.Date, fill_value=0)
print (df)
VESSEL_IMO  9821  9822  9823  9999
Date                              
2016-12-16     1     1     1     0
2016-12-17     0     1     0     0
2016-12-18     0     0     1     1
2016-12-19     0     0     0     0
2016-12-20     1     0     0     0
2016-12-21     0     0     0     1
2016-12-22     0     0     0     0
2016-12-23     0     0     0     0
2016-12-24     0     0     0     0
2016-12-25     0     0     0     0
```

Another solutions with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['a'] = 1
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.pivot(index ='Date', columns='VESSEL_IMO', values='a').fillna(0)
#if duplicated index
#df = df.pivot_table(index='Date',columns='VESSEL_IMO',values='a',fill_value=0,aggfunc='max')
print (df)
VESSEL_IMO  9821  9822  9823  9999
Date                              
2016-12-15   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
2016-12-16   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0
2016-12-17   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
2016-12-18   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0
2016-12-20   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2016-12-21   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0

df = df.reindex(df1.Date, fill_value=0).astype(int)

VESSEL_IMO  9821  9822  9823  9999
Date                              
2016-12-16     1     1     1     0
2016-12-17     0     1     0     0
2016-12-18     0     0     1     1
2016-12-19     0     0     0     0
2016-12-20     1     0     0     0
2016-12-21     0     0     0     1
2016-12-22     0     0     0     0
2016-12-23     0     0     0     0
2016-12-24     0     0     0     0
2016-12-25     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! And thank you for sample ;)